# ListView inside ListView adapter Android

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a code that simulates a Facebook feed
I would like to add a comment option to open a new listview containing several comments for each post

The main listview is defined by Adapter, how will I do a thesis in a way that clicking on a comment button will really open me up a list of different comments in each post, or show no comment if I want some of the posts to remain unanswered?
this is my adapter

```
import android.R.layout;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FacebookWallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private List<FacebookWallPost> posts;
    private List<String> comments;
    private ListView commentsListView;
    private Context activity;
    private int postsLayoutId;
    public FacebookWallAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.posts = objects;
        this.activity = context;
        this.postsLayoutId = resource;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.activity);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.postsLayoutId,parent,false);
        TextView writerName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.writerName);
        TextView date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView postText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.postText);
        ImageView profilePic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        ImageView postImage = convertView.findViewById(R.id.postImage);
        ImageView likeButtonStatus = convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeButton);
        ImageView commentsButton = convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentButton);
        FacebookWallPost thisPost = this.posts.get(position);
        writerName.setText(thisPost.getPostWriter());
        date.setText(thisPost.getDate());
        postText.setText(thisPost.getPostText());
        profilePic.setImageResource(thisPost.getProfilePic());
        postImage.setImageResource(thisPost.getPostImage());
        if(thisPost.getLikeStatus()){
            likeButtonStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_blue);

        }
        else
        {            likeButtonStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_black);
        }
        likeButtonStatus.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {
          if (thisPost.getLikeStatus())
          {

              thisPost.setLikeStatus(false);
          }
          else {
              thisPost.setLikeStatus(true);
          }
          this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        });




        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I tried to add another listview named: **commentsListView**

And a list of comments: *List **comments***

But I can't define Adapter correctly, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at expandable listviews:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

This allows you to have listviews within other listviews.